# Javascript getElementById default value not displaying in other input fields

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set a default value for an input field. My simple script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('amount').value = 1000;
</script>

<?php foreach(//code): ?>
<td>
    <input type="text" id="amount" class="amount_received" size="10" 
      value="<?php echo $sf_params-     >get('amount_received_'.$l['id']) ?>"
      name="amount_received_<?php echo $l['id'] ?>"   
      id="amount_received_<?php echo $l['id'] ?>"/>
</td>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

however,the default value displays only on the first textbox. I have a form that will display numbers of td with an id of "amount" dynamically. Rest of the textboxes remain blank.

Comment: put it in `$(document).ready` or `onload`

Comment: switch the order of script and html in your markup, and leave only one `id` attribute in the `input` tag

Comment: @JhKaiz–the OP isn't using jQuery.

Comment: so I give another option is `onload` :).

Comment: You expect there to be multiple elements with the same ID?  That way lies madness...

Comment: *"however,the default value displays only on the first textbox. I have a form that will display numbers of td with an id of "amount" dynamically"* IDs have to be **unique**! `getElementById` only returns a **single** element. It also only finds the element if it exists at the moment you call it.

Comment: (1) Put the script at the end of the document so that the DOM elements it is selecting for will be present. (2) `amount` is not a unique ID as you are using it in a loop. Use a class, or assign unique, index-based ID perhaps? Like `amount1`, `amount2` and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("amount_received");
for (var i = 0; i <= list.length; i++) {
list[i].value = 1000;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get away `getElementsByClassName("amount_received")` (https://developer.mozilla.org/EN-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName). You can then iterate over the results and set their value.

Some of the comments on the OP are right - when you have multiple IDs the same, you can only select the first one. Get them all in an array and selecting them by class instead gets you around the problem.